# Join two rows in a select with null values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I am developing a program with Oracle and I have the next problem.

I make a select beetwen different tables and my result is something like this:

```
Param1||Param2||Param3||Param4
1111     null    2222    null
1111     3333    null   4444
```

I tried to use a Group by to join the two rows, but it doesn't work because null != 3333.

The thing that I want to achieve is to recieve only one row with that select, transforming the null values into the other value. Is it possible with Group by or I need to use other things?

Thanks!

EDIT:
 The result that I want is:

```
Param1||Param2||Param3||Param4
 1111    3333    2222    4444
```

Comment: Do you only ever have two rows for the same `param1` value and would you ever have the case that both rows contained data for a parameter? If so, how would you handle merging rows with data in both?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select param1, max(param2) as param2, max(param3) as param3, max(param4) as param4
from t
group by param1;
```